# Bootstrap modal popup won't close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

When you click "inloggen", the modal pops up, which is great. But when you go to the register and back to login and back to register, etc, then a click outside of the modal won't close it anymore.

Does anybody know the problem?
I think it's an issue with the JavaScript code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">


 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/login-register.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/opmaak.css">
   <script src="../js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<title>'T Shopkartje</title>

 <style>
  .modal-header, h4, .close {
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color:white !important;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .modal-footer {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: right;
    border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
  </style>

<style>html,
body {
    height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
 width: auto!important;
   overflow-x: hidden!important;
 background-image:url('../images/achtergrond.png');
 scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.carousel,
.item,
.active {
    height: 95%;
}

.container-fluid{
background-image:url('../images/achtergrond.png');
}

.carousel-inner {
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
}

.carousel-caption{padding-bottom:80px;}

h2{font-size: 60px;}
p{padding:10px}

/* Background images are set within the HTML using inline CSS, not here */

.fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 110%;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    opacity:0.6;
}

.header {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

/**
 * Button
 */
.btn-transparent {
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}
.btn-transparent:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.btn-rounded {
  border-radius: 70px;
}

.btn-large {
  padding: 11px 45px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
/**
 * Change animation duration
 */
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInRight {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(100px, 0, 0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeInRight {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(100px, 0, 0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}
.fadeInRight {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInRight;
  animation-name: fadeInRight;
}
.footer {
    position: bottom;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 55px;
 text-align: center !important;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
 
 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar-fixed navbar-white">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   <li><a type="button" href="javascript: void(0)" id="btnlogin">Inloggen</a></li>
   <li><a type="button" href="javascript: void(0)" id="btnlogon">Registreren</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</nav>


  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="loginmodel" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header" style="padding:35px 50px;">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> Inloggen</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 50px;">
          <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="usrname"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> E-Mail</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usrname" placeholder="Enter email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="psw"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Password</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="psw" placeholder="Enter password">
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" value="" checked>Remember me</label>
            </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Inloggen</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</button>  
    <p class="pp">Geen account? <button class="btn btn-light" id="btnlogonfromin">Registreren</button></p>
          <p class="pp"><button type="button" class="btn btn-light" id="btnlogin">Passwoord Vergeten?</button></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

 <!-- Modal2 -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="logonmodel" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header" style="padding:35px 50px;">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> Registreren</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 50px;">
          <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="usrname"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Voornaam</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="voornm" placeholder="Enter Voornaam" required>
            </div>
   <div class="form-group">
              <label for="usrname"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Achternaam</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="achtrn" placeholder="Enter Achternaam" required>
            </div>
   <div class="form-group">
              <label for="usrname"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> E-Mail</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="psw"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Passwoord</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="psw" placeholder="Enter Passwoord" required>
            </div>
   <div class="form-group">
              <label for="usrname"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bed"></span> Straat + Huisnummer</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="straat" placeholder="Straat + Huisnummer" required>
            </div>
   <div class="form-group">
              <label for="usrname"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></span> Postcode + Stad</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="stad" placeholder="Postcode + Stad" required>
            </div>
   <div class="form-group">
              <label for="usrname"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span> Telefoonnummer</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="numb" placeholder="Enter Telefoonnummer" required>
            </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Registreren</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</button>  
    <p class="pp">Heeft u al een account? <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" id="btnloginfromin">Inloggen</button></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btnlogin").click(function(){
    $("#loginmodel").modal();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btnlogon").click(function(){
    $("#logonmodel").modal();
  });
});

$("#btnloginfromin").on("click", function(){
    $("#logonmodel").modal("hide");
    $("#logonmodel").on("hidden.bs.modal",function(){
    $("#loginmodel").modal("show");
    });
});

$("#btnlogonfromin").on("click", function(){
    $("#loginmodel").modal("hide");
    $("#loginmodel").on("hidden.bs.modal",function(){
    $("#logonmodel").modal("show");
    });
});
</script>
 
 <script>
function ons()
{
     location.href = "ons.html";
} 
</script>
<script>
function shopkart()
{
     location.href = "shopkart.php";
} 
</script>
<script>
function contacteren()
{
     location.href = "contacteren.html";
} 
</script>
 
 <?php
 
 
 
 ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code that opens the modal and the code that is supposed to close the modal. The link to your Pen is great and might even be necessary if someone needs to do a deep dive... but participants shouldn't be forced to go there to figure out if they will engage or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You bound a callback function on `hidden.bs.modal` that opens a modal.

```js
...
$("#loginmodel").modal("hide");
$("#loginmodel").on("hidden.bs.modal",function(){
  $("#logonmodel").modal("show");
});
...
```

**It is not necessary** and that makes a infinite modal opening. You just need to call `modal('show')` after `modal('hide')`.

```js
...
$("#btnloginfromin").on("click", function() {
  $("#logonmodel").modal("hide");
  $("#loginmodel").modal("show");
});

$("#btnlogonfromin").on("click", function() {
  $("#loginmodel").modal("hide");
  $("#logonmodel").modal("show");
});
...
```

**Snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnlogin").click(function() {
    $("#loginmodel").modal();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnlogon").click(function() {
    $("#logonmodel").modal();
  });
});

$("#btnloginfromin").on("click", function() {
  $("#logonmodel").modal("hide");
  $("#loginmodel").modal("show");
});

$("#btnlogonfromin").on("click", function() {
  $("#loginmodel").modal("hide");
  $("#logonmodel").modal("show");
});

function ons() {
  location.href = "ons.html";
}

function shopkart() {
  location.href = "shopkart.php";
}

function contacteren() {
  location.href = "contacteren.html";
}
```

```css
.modal-header,
h4,
.close {
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white !important;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.modal-footer {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: right;
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  width: auto!important;
  overflow-x: hidden!important;
  background-image: url('../images/achtergrond.png');
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.carousel,
.item,
.active {
  height: 95%;
}

.container-fluid {
  background-image: url('../images/achtergrond.png');
}

.carousel-inner {
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
}

.carousel-caption {
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 60px;
}

p {
  padding: 10px
}


/* Background images are set within the HTML using inline CSS, not here */

.fill {
  width: 100%;
  height: 110%;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.header {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}


/**
 * Button
 */

.btn-transparent {
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}

.btn-transparent:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.btn-rounded {
  border-radius: 70px;
}

.btn-large {
  padding: 11px 45px;
  font-size: 18px;
}


/**
 * Change animation duration
 */

.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInRight {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(100px, 0, 0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInRight {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(100px, 0, 0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}

.fadeInRight {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInRight;
  animation-name: fadeInRight;
}

.footer {
  position: bottom;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  text-align: center !important;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/login-register.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/opmaak.css">
  <script src="../js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


  <title>'T Shopkartje</title>


</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar-fixed navbar-white">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a type="button" href="javascript: void(0)" id="btnlogin">Inloggen</a></li>
          <li><a type="button" href="javascript: void(0)" id="btnlogon">Registreren</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="loginmodel" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header" style="padding:35px 50px;">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> Inloggen</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 50px;">
          <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="usrname"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> E-Mail</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usrname" placeholder="Enter email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="psw"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Password</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="psw" placeholder="Enter password">
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" value="" checked>Remember me</label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Inloggen</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</button>
          <p class="pp">Geen account? <button class="btn btn-light" id="btnlogonfromin">Registreren</button></p>
          <p class="pp"><button type="button" class="btn btn-light" id="btnlogin">Passwoord Vergeten?</button></p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal2 -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="logonmodel" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header" style="padding:35px 50px;">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> Registreren</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 50px;">
          <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="usrname"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Voornaam</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="voornm" placeholder="Enter Voornaam" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="usrname"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Achternaam</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="achtrn" placeholder="Enter Achternaam" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="usrname"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> E-Mail</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="psw"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Passwoord</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="psw" placeholder="Enter Passwoord" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="usrname"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bed"></span> Straat + Huisnummer</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="straat" placeholder="Straat + Huisnummer" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="usrname"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></span> Postcode + Stad</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="stad" placeholder="Postcode + Stad" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="usrname"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span> Telefoonnummer</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="numb" placeholder="Enter Telefoonnummer" required>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Registreren</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</button>
          <p class="pp">Heeft u al een account? <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" id="btnloginfromin">Inloggen</button></p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```